# WPF - Mixing style defined in dictionary with style defined in parent control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I define a custom look for Button control in a resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BaseButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I try to change the style of the window where the buttons are located.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>   
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have what I expected in WPF designer: a blue button with red text.
But in run-time, both styles are not applied and the button has default colors.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one below works.  I just moved the Style out of the MergedDictionaries and placed it on the outer ResourceDictionary.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

In your original XAML, I'm not sure why the designer was able to render it correctly while the WPF runtime didn't.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx) says though that:

*A merged ResourceDictionary does not have resource elements defined within it in markup. Instead, the merged dictionary is a ResourceDictionary with no markup child elements defined (or with no elements added through code), but with a URI specified for Source.*

It might have something to do with it.